# Add css class to specific columns of a row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following table:

[image]
[image]

When the use clicks on a particular columns of a row(excluding the first and second columns, i.e, the ID and title columns), all but the first two columns should be highlighted.

So, if I click on ID or title column, nothing should happen. Else, if I click on any other column, columns 3 to the end to should be highlighted.

I am using the following jquery but it does not seem to do the job:

**JQuery:**

```
$('#books tbody').on('click', 'tr  td:not(:first-child) td:not(:second-child)', function () {
      $('tr  td:not(:first-child) td:not(:second-child)').toggleClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.even.selected td {
    background-color: rgb(48, 225, 230);
    !important; /* Add !important to make sure override datables base styles */
}

.odd.selected td {
    background-color: rgb(48, 225, 230);
    !important; /* Add !important to make sure override datables base styles */
}
```

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Try `'tr  td:not(:first-child):not(:second-child)'` for a logical and on the td.  For the inner logic I'd just do a slice.  `$('tr td').slice(2).toggleClass('selected');`

Comment: And !important should be before the semicolon. i.e background-color: rgb(48, 225, 230) !important;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes I have made for the particular code:

- Instead of defining rows as even and odd, you can `use the :even or :odd` selector in Jquery to determine and apply the respective class.
- We're making use of `td:nth-child(n+3)` to determine that the function to toggle class will only run if the `td isn't the 1st or the 2nd one`.
- Appropriately, we check whether the parent (tr) of the selected td is odd or even and store the respective class in a `selected` variable.
- We then `toggle the class` for the `current selected td's parent` on which the `first and second td won't have the class applied` to.

```js
var selected;
$("#books tbody tr td:nth-child(n+3)").click(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().is(":even"))
    selected = "evenrow";
  else
    selected = "oddrow"
  $(this).parent().children().not('td:eq(0), td:eq(1)').toggleClass(selected);
});
```

```css
tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.evenrow {
  background-color: rgb(48, 225, 230) !important;
}

.oddrow {
  background-color: rgb(255, 225, 230) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="books" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>other</th>
      <th>another</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>$200</td>
      <td>$300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>$200</td>
      <td>$300</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I forgot to mention that I am using data table to populate the data. And I believe datatable has pre inserted class="even" and odd. That is why when I follow your answer, my table shows red and blue rows on page load instead of on click. How should I fix that?

Comment: @bangbang Updated. Just change the class names in the Jquery and CSS, this way there's no predefined css for the "even" or "odd" classes.

Comment: Yes, I did that too just now. Thank you very much for your help. You saved my time.

Comment: @bangbang No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, your selectors are just a little off

```
tr  td:not(:first-child) td:not(:second-child)
```

Is actually saying "a td that is not the second child under a td that is not the first child under a tr"

I'm not actually convinced that `:second-child` is a valid selector either.

Try changing that selector to this:

```
tr td + td + td
```

The `+` operator means "directly following element" - so the above says "a td that immediatley follows a td that immediatley follows a td"